# Fuzzing SNMP version 2 and 3

Tags: snmp, fuzzing

I want to fuzz test SNMP agents for version 2 and 3. The existing opensource fuzzing frameworks(Peach,Spike and others) lack the support for transforming the defined DataModel into ASN.1-BER in-order to be understandable by the agent. All i want to do is to create a database of the fuzzed/malformed inputs and then feed them to the agent.
Suggestions required regarding creation of malformed inputs, or is there any existing framework(i may be missing) which can let me do that in an easiest way possible?

Comment: I think you're going to have to be much more specific. "How do I test an SNMP agent" is extremely broad!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can you name any tool or a way out for creating crafted snmp packets?

Comment: Crafted in what way? Do you just want to vary the OIDs and varbinds? Net-SNMP's native tools will be fine for that. Or do you want to stress test the agent with actual _malformed_ PDUs? In that case you can just send the required bytes over the wire, or use some kind of simulator? So many options, all depending on your needs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right! Packet crafting can be done by Scapy but i don't want to test the target for any specific input rather mutating the fields in PDUs based on some mutation strategy and then monitor the target for each mutated input.

Comment: I'd just do it myself using like a Net-SNMP datatype, a couple of lines of C and a network connection! Of course the way you "define" those tests is up to you - you could bake it into your code or come up with some human-friendly description in a textfile for your code to parse. The possibilities are endless!

Answer (score 0):

In both [Kitty](https://github.com/cisco-sas/kitty) and [boofuzz](https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz) you can implement an ASN.1 DER encoder and then define it as the encoder for the fields, as each type of field accepts an encoder in the constructor.

In addition, in the case of Kitty, you can use the already implemented [`ScapyField`](https://github.com/cisco-sas/katnip/blob/master/katnip/model/low_level/scapy.py), which allows fuzzing based on the mutation capabilities of scapy.

Comment: That's helpful. But aren't you people looking for adding ASN1. DER encoder in kitty source? because most of the protocols use ASN.1.

Comment: We add things as we need them, and accept pull requests happily.